# Stock Highcharts date format

Tags: highcharts

I am creating a JSON file for the Stock Highcharts charting library. I need to know what format the date needs to be in. I'm currently using a string with YYYY/MM/DD as the date.

The JSON that the example gives is here: https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-ohlcv.json. The first number is the date, but I do not understand the format. Does any one know what format that is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), albeit with millisecond precision:

```js
console.log(new Date(1571059800000))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these docs articles, should help you to understand what format is required in Highcharts:

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes#datetime

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.data.x